# simplexml_load_file returning XML file twice

Tags: php, xml

I am stumped. I am trying to connect to a simple API that returns a XML file. The problem is when I go to the URL in the browser everything looks good, but when I call that URL in my PHP it duplicates the object twice. So all the values are duplicated and there are 2 objects when the URL only has 1.

**What I have in my PHP file (I have more, but I have it raw as possible to make sure I am eliminating any user error problems):**

```
print_r( simplexml_load_file('https://api.uptimerobot.com/getMonitors?apiKey=API_KEY_NUMBER') );
```

**What I get when I load the url in a browser (Removed irrelevant data for simplicity and privacy)**

```
<monitors offset="0" limit="50" total="96">
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
  <monitor id="ID" friendlyname="FRIENDLYNAME" url="URL"... />
</monitors>
```

**What I get when I print_r() from my site (simplified for privacy and simplicity)**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [offset] => 0 [limit] => 50 [total] => 96 ) [monitor] => Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ...  
    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ...
) ) ) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [offset] => 0 [limit] => 50 [total] => 96 ) [monitor] => Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ... 
    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ...  
    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => ID [friendlyname] => FRIENDLYNAME [url] => URL ...
) ) )
```

I have ran out of ideas! I was first having the issue when I was trying to do below and it returned the value twice.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.uptimerobot.com/getMonitors?apiKey=API_KEY');

$total_sites = $xml['total'];
echo $total_sites;
```

The echo would return `9696`

Comment: Maybe you are including that code twice? If `echo $total_items` is printed twice, that means, that the problem is not in `simplexml_load`, but with your code somewhere. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: Unfortunately I only have the echo on there once. I moved it all to a new page with nothing but the above to make sure none of the other code was causing it... unfortunately it is doing the same things, and when I remove the 1 echo case, then nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review, I was in fact adding it twice. I removed one of the references and it worked like a charm!